# How to edit the UITableViewCell using UIButton?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4.2, uitoolbar

I am new to iPhone programming, and stuck in a situation.

The situation is that I want UITableView to enter the editing mode on UIButton click. Upon entering edit mode there I should have a check box on each cell. And I wanted to change the checked cells images if I click UIToolBarButton.

How can I achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to turn the checked UITableViewCells's images to UIToolBarButton, then think on it twice bcoz if table is of 100 cells & if user selects just 10 cells then how r u going to show 10 UITollBar icons.

Comment: I am not going to add 100 toolbar items, but want to change the images of cells on the click of tollbar items

Comment: check edited answer. is this what u want?

Comment: This should really be multiple questions since they are asking about very different things.  One for the button to enter edit mode, and one for changing the checkbox cell images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like lnafziger said to enter the editing mode call

```
[self.tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

in the function that is connected to your button.

To show checkboxes on your cells when the table is in editing mode add these lines to `viewDidLoad` :

```
[self.tableView setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
```

Then for your UIBarButtonItem to change the images add a for loop with the `[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]` array, and change each cells image like so:

```
NSArray *paths = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    //change cell.imageView's image
}
```

Comment: It seems working fine, but have a little problem. It only changes the images of the cells which are visible at the moment and do not change the images of the cells which are selected but not visible. Is there any solution for that

Comment: in the cellForRowAtIndexPath or willDisplayCellAtIndexPath method change the image if `cell.selected` Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To enter edit mode using a button, call the following code from the button's action method:

```
[self.tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

To change the checkBox, you need to set the `editingAccessoryView` of the cell to your custom view (typically in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`).